# Can I use a raspberry pi 3 to send live sensor data over bluetooth using an HID profile?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, hid, oculusgo

My project is to send a single stream of sensor data to an Oculus Go headset, which currently does not support bluetooth connections for anything except gamepads (HID profile). Using Unity (on the Oculus) I can read inputs from gamepads as an axis (-1 to 1, 1024bits I think) and this is how I plan to send my sensor data into the game.

The problem I am facing is how to create an HID bluetooth profile on the RPi3 and then how to stream my sensor data over it.

Thanks in advance for any help!